# Magento 2.1 Load Product By ID and Change SKU Programmatically

Tags: magento2, php

I used a third party service to transfer products from woocommerce to magento, but many of the products don't have SKUs.

I attempted to do this using a CSV file containing a column of IDs and a column of SKUS. Help me make this happen.

```
<?php
umask(0);
if (($handle = fopen("skus.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product_id = $data[0];
        $newsku = $data[1];
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
        if($product) { 
        echo 'working';
            $product->setSku($newsku);
            $product->save();
            echo  $product->getName() . ' SKU updated';
            echo "\n";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does that CSV file come from? Did you do it own your own? What is the objective behind that? Maybe another solution is possible.

Comment: I based this code around a solution for this problem in older magento versions
http://www.hummingbirduk.com/how-to-change-skus-in-bulk-in-magento/
The CSV just contains two columns one with product IDS and the other SKUs. However when trying to use your solutions I just fed example values to the function I didn't use the CSV. The csvs job can also be done with loops

Comment: You might be able to do this on the Magento 2 "Import" screen, which allows you to add/update products in bulk from a CSV: https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/a-guide-on-how-to-import-export-products-in-magento-2

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by creating an extension using this function

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

}

then in my PHTML

```
$numofproducts = 1088;
$id = 1;
$sku = 1000;
while($id < $numofproducts) {
    $_product = $block->getProductById($id);
    echo $_product->getEntityId();
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_product->getName();
    echo $_product->getSKU();
    $_product->setSKU($sku)->save();
    echo $_product->getSKU();
    $id = $id + 1;
    $sku = $sku + 1;
}
```

Comment: Wowowo changing SKU in a template??? NOT a good idea.

Comment: I asked this question when I was 18 and trying to get something done for work with no programming experience. Happy to delete this answer if you think it's dangerous, but it'd be helpful if you gave more context. I'm a professional software engineer now, but I don't work with Magento/PHP and completely forgot that I wrote this question in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

In such a quick-and-dirty script this might work:

```
<?php
umask(0);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$loader = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

if (($handle = fopen("skus.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $product_id = $data[0];
        $newsku = $data[1];
        $product = $loader->create()->load($product_id);
        if($product) { 
            echo 'working';
            $product->setSku($newsku);
            $product->save();
            echo  $product->getName() . ' SKU updated';
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

As using the ObjectManager is discouraged, in a Magento module it would look more like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader
) {
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
}

public function changeSku($id, $newSKU)
{
    $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    $product->setSku('BAZ')->save();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, the code didn't run, I'm not sure if the path is correct as I can't locate that specific path on Magento. I am a novice in Magento/PHP and apologize if this sounds naive.

Comment: Hm okay, it is not really standalone code - it is to be used in a Magento module :-/

Comment: I ran the changeSku function with test values to see if I could implement it in my initial code, am I unable to do this via script?

Comment: Updated my answer to more suit your question ... good luck (untested)

Comment: Appreciate your help and patience man!

Comment: Tell me if it worked - if not, what are the error messages...

Comment: Same error as before, Class 'Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager' not found

Comment: Do you think this is a magento 2.1 change? or installation error?

Comment: Wait are you running the script like this? You have to initialize some part of Magento first ... have a look at the index.php ... copy it and paste your code near the end. ..

Comment: Hey sorry, after doing some scourging I've wrote a simple magento mod, would you just run the changeSku function in the template file to make it work?

Comment: No in a class .. best thing would be you make a shell command :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, I had to learn more about magento to solve this problem, my apologies for likely giving you a headache

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this

```
protected $prodMod;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $prodModel
){
   $this->prodModel = $prodModel;
}

public function loadById($productId){
   $prod = $prodModel->getResource()->load( $prodModel, $productId );
   if(!$prod->getId())
   {
       throw new \Exception(__("not found"));
   }

   $prod->setSku('FOO')->save();
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the loadbyid function for id (1) and it didn't work, I believe the path is wrong. I am actually using Magento 2.1, my apologies. I appreciate your help